Infinitary provability logics
For $A$ a countable admissible set, let $\mathcal{L}_A=\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}\cap A$ be the fragment of infinitary first-order logic living inside $A$. Let $\mathsf{PA}_A$ be the following $\mathcal{L}_A$-theory (the motivation for that name is that $\mathsf{PA}_{\mathsf{HF}}$ is basically just first-order Peano arithmetic in disguise):

The usual first-order axioms of $\mathsf{KP}$, with foundation phrased in the strong way (as a scheme ranging over all formulas).

For each $a\in A$, the sentence $\exists !x(\eta_a(x))$, where the formulas $\eta_a(x)$ are defined recursively by $\eta_a(x)\equiv \forall y(y\in x\leftrightarrow\bigvee_{b\in a}\eta_b(y))$.


Up to isomorphism, models of $\mathsf{PA}_A$ are exactly admissible sets which are end extensions of $A$. Barwise's work lets us lift the basic ideas of provability-from-$\mathsf{PA}$ in the logic $\mathsf{FOL}$ to Barwise's notion of provability-from-$\mathsf{PA}_A$ in the logic $\mathcal{L}_A$. In particular, the direct analogue of Lob's theorem holds. This makes me curious about the corresponding notion of "$A$-provability logic:"

Let $\mathsf{PL}_A$ be the set of infinitary propositional modal formulas which are elements of $A$ and which are correct (= true in $V$) under every substitution of a $\mathcal{L}_A[\in]$-sentences for propositional atoms when we interpret "$\Box$" as Barwise's provability predicate for $\mathsf{PA}_A$. Is there a snappy description of $\mathsf{PL}_A$ in terms of $A$?

There are several natural subquestions here:

Is the finitary part of $\mathsf{PL}_A$ is just $\mathsf{GL}=\mathsf{PL}_{\mathsf{HF}}$? (I strongly suspect that the answer is yes.)

Another natural subquestion is to ask at least for the case of $\mathsf{PL}_{L_{\omega_1^{CK}}}$. (Or, restrict to levels of $L$ and add $\mathsf{V=L}$ to the axioms of $\mathsf{PA}_A$.)


But any progress on any of these, let alone the main question, seems to require modifying Solovay's completeness theorem in nontrivial ways which I don't see how to do. (Maybe the first subquestion is actually attackable by arguing that any $\varphi\not\in\mathsf{GL}$ is "obviously" not in any $\mathsf{PL}_A$, but I don't actually see how to do that either.)

I know next to nothing about admissible sets and Barwise provability predicate. Does this predicate admit a notion of a total order on “proofs” so that you can define an analogue of the usual witness comparison sentences $\exists x,(\mathrm{Proof}(x,\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)\land\forall y<x,\neg\mathrm{Proof}(y,\ulcorner\psi\urcorner))$? If you can do it in such a way that axioms of the Guaspari–Solovay logic $\mathbf R^-$ are valid, then the finitary part of the provability logic must be $\mathsf{GL}$ (or $\mathsf{GL}+\Box^n\bot$ for some $n$, but I suppose you can rule this out).

On a second thought, I would also need (a multi-dimensional version of) Gödel’s diagonal lemma to hold, which does not automatically follow from the one for Robinson’s $Q$ as the codes of infinitary $\mathcal L_A$-sentences are not just natural numbers.

@EmilJeřábek Re: your first comment, this happens if $A\models\mathsf{V=L}$. But there are also countable admissible sets for which this fails. (Basically, $A$-proof-objects are no worse - or better - than general elements of $A$. But under $\mathsf{V=L}$ we have a nicely-definable well-ordering of the universe.)

@EmilJeřábek Re: your second comment, I believe the diagonal lemma does still hold appropriately via the usual argument, with numerals being replaced with appropriate infinitary canonical descriptions (as in the infinitary axioms of $\mathsf{PA}_A$). Does this not work?

It does not have to be an order on the proofs themselves. It might be something like “there is a proof of $\phi$ of rank $\alpha$ such that there is no proof of $\psi$ of smaller rank” for $\Box\phi\preceq\Box\psi$, and “... of smaller or equal rank” for $\Box\phi\prec\Box\psi$. Does such a stratification make sense here? If so, this should satisfy most axioms of $\mathbf R^-$; in particular, since you have full transfinite induction, any provable formula should have a proof of least rank, which should take care of $\Box\phi\to(\Box\phi\prec\Box\psi)\lor(\Box\psi\preceq\Box\phi)$. ...

... What is going to be the main problem is whether such a definition has low enough complexity so that $(\Box\phi\preceq\Box\psi)\to\Box(\Box\phi\preceq\Box\psi)$ and $(\Box\phi\prec\Box\psi)\to\Box(\Box\phi\prec\Box\psi)$ are valid. But as I wrote, I know basically nothing about admissible sets and about this notion of provability, so someone else (you?) would have to figure this out.
